# Extract dates/names of visitors who visit repeatedly within any 90 day period

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Column A: dates of visits, Column B: name of person visiting.

Want to extract the dates & names of any person visiting multiple times with-in 90 days of a previous visit.

Example Data:
1/01/2020  Jones, Bob
2/01/2020  Jones, Bob
3/01/2020  Jones, Bob
5/01/2020  Jane, Mary
10/01/2020 Jane, Mary

Desired Output:
2/01/2020 Jones, Bob
3/01/2020 Jones, Bob

Mary's visits do not get output because she did not re-visit within 90 days.
It would be OK if Bob's initial visit was also output, but that is not necessary.

I have a sheet with about 10,000 rows of data to parse. Much appreciate any advice!

This seems to be over my head, I searched stack for similar situations without luck. I'm not sure if this is even possible?  Fingers crossed!

Comment: Assuming your data is sorted by person and by date, you can use a formula like this `=ifs(B2=B1,A2-A1<90,TRUE,FALSE))` where column B is name and column A is date. Then filter column C to `TRUE`. The first entry of this formula would be in `C2` assuming no header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=filter(A:B,map(A:A,B:B,lambda(Σ,Λ,if(or(Σ="",Λ=""),,days(Σ,chooserows(filter(A1:Σ,B1:Λ=Λ),-2)))))<90,A:A<>"")
```

[image]